# How to cast compare function with typedef in c

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I am creating a compare function to use the qsort() but I can't properly cast the elements. I tried with different things, but it never works. Can someone please explain me the correct logic of doing this? Thank you in advance!

```
typedef struct _stringa {
    char* string;
    int freq;
} stringa;


int compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2) {

    if (*(stringa*)elem1.freq < *(stringa*)elem2.freq) {
        return -1;
    } else if (*(stringa*)elem1.freq > *(stringa*)elem2.freq) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: 
Sorry for the second question, but my sorting doesn't work and it seems to 'delete' elements. Is this the right way to call qsort?

```
qsort(ARRAY, ARRAY_DIMENSION, sizeof(struct _stringa), compare);
```

Comment: What is the type of `ARRAY`? Is this array of `struct` ?

Comment: Yes this is how it is defined:
 stringa **newarray = NULL; 
    newarray = malloc ( n * sizeof (struct _stringa *) );

Comment: Change `sizeof(struct _stringa)` to `sizeof(struct _stringa *)`.

Comment: Thank you it works now. Just need to fix other bugs, because sort is behaving strangely

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're being caught out by an order of operations issue. In order to prevent that and make the code more readable, you could cast in one operation and then compare afterwards:

```
int compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2) {
    stringa *first = (stringa *)elem1;
    stringa *second = (stringa *)elem2;

    if (first->freq < second->freq) {
        return -1;
    } else if (first->freq > second->freq) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need one more level of parenthesization

```
int compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2) {

    if ( (*(stringa*)elem1 ).freq < ( *(stringa*)elem2 ).freq) ) {
        return -1;
    } else if ( (*(stringa*)elem1 ).freq > ( *(stringa*)elem2 ).freq) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without `(*(stringa*)elem1 )`, compiler will cast `elem1.freq` to `stringa*` and then will try to dereference `elem1.freq`.

**EDIT:** Since you declared `ARRAY` as pointer to pointer to `_stringa`, you need to pass the size of pointer to `_stringa` to the `qsort` as thirs argument:

```
qsort(ARRAY, ARRAY_DIMENSION, sizeof(struct _stringa *), compare);
```

Comment: Thank you haccks it works! Could you please read my edit too ?